# Automapper, mapping IEnumearble<Foo> to IEnumearble<FooDto>

Tags: automapper

I ve been trying to do something like this:

```
    ...
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Foo>, IEnumerable<FooDto>>();
var fooDtos = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Foo>, IEnumerable<FooDto>>(foos);
```

Keep in mind that Foo is an entity but the properties are exactly the same that FooDto.
The Result of fooDtos is an empty enumerable 
Tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok Its simple I should have mapped like this :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
```

and that works Doh!